# using Cx_freeze with kivy in python 3.3 on windows error

Tags: python, windows, kivy, cx-freeze

I am using kivy 1.8.0 on Windows.

After finishing coding, I ran `cx_freeze` like this:

```
python setup.py build
```

This is `setup.py`:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name = 'KR Searcher',
version = '0.1',
description = 'aaaa',
executables = [Executable('kivyTest2.py',base=base)])
```

After freezing I ran `kivyTest2.exe`, then this error popped up:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 939, in emit
  stream.write(msg)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

and this repeats.

Before freezing `kivyTest2.p`y runs well without any errors.

So how can I make `.exe` files with `cx_freeze` with `Kivy` without using Python 2.x?

Comment: Either your code or Kivy is trying to write logs to stdout/stderr, which doesn't work with the Win32GUI base (there's no console to display the output). You'll need to point logging to a file, or configure it to discard them. See the [logging docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/logging) for how to do that.

Comment: Thx for answering. But my lack of knowledge, I just ran on Kivy on python 2.x for now. I'll keep finding the way anyway. thanx again.

Comment: I'm not sure why Python 2 vs 3 would make a difference here, but I'm glad you got it working.